# Script is only affecting one instance of a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Guard prefab that has two child components: one for detecting if the target is in range and one for detecting if the target is in catch range. The OnTriggerEnter for the catch range work on both instances of the Prefab. But the one for detecting if the targt is in range only works for the first instance of the Prefab that spawned.
Both child objects have a rigidbody that is set to Kinematic and have their own colliders for their tasks. The Parent has no Colliders.
In my script for detecting if its in range i have both of the trigger functions:

```
TGuardMovement mov;

void Start()
{
    mov = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Guard").GetComponent<TGuardMovement>();
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D a_Collider2D)
{
    if (a_Collider2D.gameObject.CompareTag("Animal"))
    {
        //invoke chase
        mov.InvokeChase();
    } 
}


public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D a_Collider2D)
{
    //cancel Invoke
    if (a_Collider2D.gameObject.CompareTag("Animal"))
    {
        mov.CancelInvokeChase();
    }
        
}
```

TGuardMovement is the script on the parent which handles the AI Movement

```
 public void InvokeChase()
{
    InvokeRepeating("UpdatePath", 0f, .5f);
}

public void CancelInvokeChase()
{
    CancelInvoke("UpdatePath");
}
```

Those are the functions thate are being called by the child object. Simply invoking the function to start the chasing and stopping it respectivly.
this is the UpdatePath() function:

```
void UpdatePath()
{       
    if(m_GState == GuardState.PATROLING)
    {
        TriggerMovement();
    }

    else if (m_GState == GuardState.CHASING)
    {
        if (m_Seeker.IsDone())
        {
            m_Seeker.StartPath(m_Rb2D.position, targetGO.transform.position, OnPathComplete);
        }

    }
    if (targetGO == null)
    {
        m_Seeker.StartPath(m_Rb2D.position, m_objManager.m_goTGuardObject.transform.position, OnPathComplete);
    }
}
```

Im kinda at the end of my ideas what the error could be. The trigger event for moving is triggered by the unmoving prefab but it doesnt start moving.Even just teleporting the instances only moves the first spawned.

Comment: I believe it may only be working for one because you are using `object = FindGameObjectWithTag` instead of `objects[] = FindGameObjectsWithTag`.  Please realize this is pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely in the Start function of the first script shown. `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(string)` only returns one `GameObject`, the first one it finds.

Some possible fixes:

- You could use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(string)`, Notice that it says `Objects` instead of `Object`, and store it in an `GameObjects[]`.
- If the guards are being instantiated at runtime, you could store refrences to the guards then by creating a list:

  ```
   public List<GameObject> guards = new List<GameObject>();
  ```

  then in the spawning function:

  ```
   guards.Add(Instantiate(guardPrefab));
  ```
- If the guards might come and go and you just want to get all the guards in the area you could use `Physics.OverlapSphere(...);`. It can be used similarly to a raycast except it gets all the colliders in an area. You can store these in an array and access their scripts when you want to.

Comment: Note that ti is [`FindGameObjectsWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) not `FindGameObjectWithTags` ;)

Comment: Lol I thought something was off.